# one simple question about c# combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

my comboboxes is filling on dropdown i want if user dont select something in it and press somewhere or just close dropdown combobox value was null
Sorry for my english

Comment: C# does not have a combobox. WinForms, WebForms or WPF?

Comment: Is this related to some previous question? If yes, you should link it.

Comment: I think he is talking about dropdownlist or listbox ?

Comment: @user please give more info so we can give better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the combo box is opened then closed(for any reason) and the user did not select something, the combobox will have the same value it had before it was opened.

Note: If you are filling the combobox with values from a datasource and you want it to have a null value, then set the `selectedIndex` of the combobox to -1

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking null control? If yes, you can handle this with these control.

```
    if(comBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Please Select Any Item");
    return;
    }
```